# Concatenate JSONArrays

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, concatenation

I am using [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) under the `org.json` Package.

My first JSONArray is like:

> [["249404","VPR249404"],["249403","VPR249403"],["249391","M249391"]]

and Second

> [["249386","M249386"],["249385","M249385(I)"],["249384","I249384"]]

So I'd like to append new JSONArray to my first JSONArray.

I am working on Java and Android. I have heard about [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library, but I don't know whether it can help me or not but I don't want any other dependency in my Android Application.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
private JSONArray concatArray(JSONArray arr1, JSONArray arr2)
        throws JSONException {
    JSONArray result = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length(); i++) {
        result.put(arr1.get(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length(); i++) {
        result.put(arr2.get(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

I don't have a compiler right now to test, but you can give it a try and see if it works (or, at least, it gives you an idea of how to do it).

**EDIT**

This version could concat multiple arrays (`concatArray(arr1, arr2, arr3)`):

```
private JSONArray concatArray(JSONArray... arrs)
        throws JSONException {
    JSONArray result = new JSONArray();
    for (JSONArray arr : arrs) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            result.put(arr.get(i));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How to keep duplicate values once only?

Comment: Add to Set first and result.put(Set.toArray) @Pratik Butani

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
private JSONArray concatArray(@NotNull JSONArray jsArr1, @NotNull JSONArray jsArr2) {
    List<Object> list = jsArr1.toList();
    list.addAll(jsArr2.toList());
    return new JSONArray(list);
}
```

Comment: org.json.JSONException: JSONArray initial value should be a string or collection or array.
 at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:203)

Answer (score -3):

Use ...

```
jarray1.addAll(jarray2);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: JSONArray does not provide addAll that method.