# Android: JSON Custom Merge

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have created two JSON like following,

**First Array:**

```
[
   {
      "id":255,
      "is_new":0,
      "is_checked":true,
      "name":"Towel Rack 650",
      "is_favourite":false
   },
   {
      "id":257,
      "is_new":0,
      "is_checked":true,
      "name":"Towel Rod 450",
      "is_favourite":false
   },
   {
      "id":259,
      "is_new":0,
      "is_checked":true,
      "name":"Napkin Ring - Round",
      "is_favourite":false
   }
]
```

**Second Array:**

```
[
   {
      "id":258,
      "is_new":0,
      "is_checked":false,
      "name":"Towel Rod 650",
      "is_favourite":true
   },
   {
      "id":259,
      "is_new":0,
      "is_checked":false,
      "name":"Napkin Ring - Round",
      "is_favourite":true
   }
]
```

**In that I have to merge both array and also want to keep duplicate values once in final array.**

I used following [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4590786/1318946) for merging.

```
private JSONArray concatArray(JSONArray arr1, JSONArray arr2)
        throws JSONException {
    JSONArray result = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length(); i++) {
        result.put(arr1.get(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length(); i++) {
        result.put(arr2.get(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am getting:

```
[
   {
      "id":255,
      "is_new":0,
      "is_checked":true,
      "name":"Towel Rack 650",
      "is_favourite":false
   },
   {
      "id":257,
      "is_new":0,
      "is_checked":true,
      "name":"Towel Rod 450",
      "is_favourite":false
   },
   {
      "id":259,
      "is_new":0,
      "is_checked":true,
      "name":"Napkin Ring - Round",
      "is_favourite":false
   },
   {
      "id":258,
      "is_new":0,
      "is_checked":false,
      "name":"Towel Rod 650",
      "is_favourite":true
   },
   {
      "id":259,
      "is_new":0,
      "is_checked":false,
      "name":"Napkin Ring - Round",
      "is_favourite":true
   }
]
```

In that I am getting duplicate values of **`id`** **259** which has different values of `is_checked` and `is_favourite` which I want `true` value for both like:

```
{
    "id":259,
    "is_new":0,
    "is_checked":true,
    "name":"Napkin Ring - Round",
    "is_favourite":true
}
```

I have also tried `SparseArray` but not succeed. Is there any way to do this?

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of the duplicate JSON object (with the id = 259) or are you trying to modify its "is_checked" value ? (Sorry I didn't fully understand what you're aiming at)

Comment: I agree. I don't understand when you want to kepe duplicates and when you don't

Comment: I dont want duplicate values two times, i need it just once.

Comment: I guess there is no easier way. You have to write it yourself. May be in concatArray(), in the second for loop, parse the array and check for existing id and add it.

Comment: @JDev I want values of `is_checked` and `is_favourite` is `true` it its `id` two times in array.

Comment: @SeshuVinay You are right but i think it will take more time to execute. if i have only 5 object in my JSON then it will loop 25 times.

Comment: Can you fix it where the JSON is being built? that's what you need to fix unless you cant change it?

Comment: No, I can fix at the time of built because I am creating it in different way. @meda

Comment: and when it is duplicated you only wanna keep the one which has true?

Comment: I just want to do that if duplicate found then both key is `true` - `is_checked` and `is_favourite`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `SparseArray`(key:id,value:each JSONObject in your JSONArray) to save your jsonobjects,every get a jsonobject,first check if its id has existed in SparseArray,if not,insert it.or you will do your logic to decide whether to insert it or update it or ignore it.

At last,if you want to get a JSONArray as return type,then add all SparseArray's values to your JSONArray result.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I wrote the code for you:

First, preparing the objects:

```
        JSONArray arr1 = new JSONArray(),arr2 = new JSONArray(),result = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jobj.put("id", "255");
            jobj.put("is_new", 0);
            jobj.put("is_checked", true);
            jobj.put("name", "Towel Rack 650");
            jobj.put("is_favourite", false);
            arr1.put(jobj);
            jobj = new JSONObject();
            jobj.put("id", "257");
            jobj.put("is_new", 0);
            jobj.put("is_checked", true);
            jobj.put("name", "Towel Rod 450");
            jobj.put("is_favourite", false);
            arr1.put(jobj);
            jobj = new JSONObject();
            jobj.put("id", "259");
            jobj.put("is_new", 0);
            jobj.put("is_checked", true);
            jobj.put("name", "Napkin Ring - Round");
            jobj.put("is_favourite", false);
            arr1.put(jobj);

            jobj = new JSONObject();
            jobj.put("id", "258");
            jobj.put("is_new", 0);
            jobj.put("is_checked", false);
            jobj.put("name", "Towel Rod 650");
            jobj.put("is_favourite", true);
            arr2.put(jobj);
            jobj = new JSONObject();
            jobj.put("id", "259");
            jobj.put("is_new", 0);
            jobj.put("is_checked", false);
            jobj.put("name", "Napkin Ring - Round");
            jobj.put("is_favourite", true);
            arr2.put(jobj);

            result = concatArray(arr1, arr2);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Then, the method:

```
private JSONArray concatArray(JSONArray arr1, JSONArray arr2)
            throws JSONException {
        JSONArray result = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jobj1 = new JSONObject(),jobj2 = new JSONObject(),tmpobj = new JSONObject();
        Set<String> objectsList = new HashSet<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length(); i++) {
            if(objectsList.add(arr1.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"))){
                result.put(arr1.getJSONObject(i));
            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length(); i++) {
            if(objectsList.add(arr2.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"))){
                result.put(arr2.getJSONObject(i));
            } else {
                jobj1 = arr2.getJSONObject(i);
                int index = 0;
                for(int j = 0; j < result.length(); j++){
                    if(result.getJSONObject(j).getString("id").equals(jobj1.getString("id"))){
                        jobj2 = result.getJSONObject(j);
                        index = j;
                    }
                }
                tmpobj.put("id", jobj2.getString("id"));
                tmpobj.put("is_new", jobj2.getInt("is_new"));
                if(jobj1.getBoolean("is_checked")||jobj2.getBoolean("is_checked")){
                    tmpobj.put("is_checked", true);
                } else {
                    tmpobj.put("is_checked", false);
                }
                tmpobj.put("name", jobj2.getString("name"));
                if(jobj1.getBoolean("is_favourite")||jobj2.getBoolean("is_favourite")){
                    tmpobj.put("is_favourite", true);
                } else {
                    tmpobj.put("is_favourite", false);
                }
                result.put(index, tmpobj);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```